# Self-built Voigt fit optimization

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting

The Voigt fit I have calculated myself by the convolution of a Gaussian and a Lorentzian does not represent the data at all. Are my starting values sooo bad? What is the problem? For every hint I am thankful ;)
I do not want to use `VoigtDistribution` =)

```
Data={{470.31,0.00687762},{474.432,0.00724475},{478.551,0.00580377},{482.667,0.00495091},{486.78,0.00764016},{490.89,0.0147269},{494.997,0.0375041},{499.102,0.0643207},{503.204,0.0667798},{507.303,0.0484502},{511.399,0.019887},{515.492,0.00842662},{519.582,0.00550438},{523.67,0.00118737},{527.755,0.000607094}};

fg[v_,mu_,sigma_]=Sqrt[2*Pi*sigma]^{-1}*Exp[ -{v-mu}^2/{2*sigma^2} ];
fl[v_,x0_,gamma_]=1/{Pi*gamma}*{gamma^2/{{v-x0}^2+{gamma/2}^2}};
Voi[Ampl_?NumberQ,v_?NumberQ,mu_?NumberQ,sigma_?NumberQ,x0_?NumberQ,gamma_?NumberQ,b_?NumberQ]:=Ampl*NIntegrate[fg[dummyv,mu,sigma]*fl[v-dummyv,x0,gamma],{dummyv,-Infinity,Infinity},MinRecursion->4,AccuracyGoal->10]+b;

FitFnc=NonlinearModelFit[Data,Voi[Ampl,v,mu,sigma,x0,gamma,b],{{Ampl,400},{mu,4},{sigma,0.1},{x0,5},{gamma,0.1},{b,0.003}},v,MaxIterations->100];
Print[Show[ListPlot[Data],Plot[FitFnc[v],{v,450,560},PlotStyle->Red],PlotRange->All]];
sol=FitFnc["BestFitParameters"]
```

[image]

Comment: How was your data obtained?  If you really are fitting a probability distribution from a random sample, then you should have counts of binned data or multiple observations.  You seem to have maybe relative frequencies of binned data?  If you don't have counts or a random sample but rather measurements of some kind, then you have a regression situation.  But if it is a regression, then why fit something that happens to be a convolution of two different probability distributions?  In short, "How do you get your data and what is it that you really want?"

Comment: If your data consists of relative frequencies, then the area under the connected points is around 1.23 (`Mean[Differences[Data[[All, 1]]]] Total[Data[[All, 2]]]`) so fitting a probability density with an area of 1.0 won't ever be a great fit.

Comment: The data is obtained by averaging 10 (more or less equal) spectra. The frequencies shown are not relative, compared to each other. Only the whole average spectrum was normalized ( xvalue 0-3000), but since the data I want to fit is only a small part (~470-540), it is a coincidence that it is 1.23. The physical explanation of the lineshape can be described by a convolution of a Lorentzian and a Gaussian. In order to characterize this peak the general procedure is to fit a Voigt profile, determine the integral or sometimes only the peak maximum. What do you mean by regression?

Comment: Did you notice that you had used braces instead of parentheses in your definition of the Gaussian and Lorentzian profiles? That may be what's tripping up your fits. Your initial guesses also look off, e.g. why start with an amplitude of `400` when the peak of your data is a shade under 0.07?